# iPhone:video url is not playin using MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I have given one url to play video file for that I use following code to play the video

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hddeo.com/video/more.html"];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];;

    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(110,375,540,250);
    // player.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 375, 600, 415);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

in simulator video doesnot play
I don't know why this happens

if you have any idea plz share it

thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The content URL that you passed is an HTML page which has an embedded SWF file.  `MPMoviePlayerController` expects a content URL that points directly to a video file, for example "http://www.example.com/video.mp4".

Just a note, iOS devices do not support Adobe Flash files.

Comment: @iPhone I'm afraid you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this code   

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hddeo.com/video/more.html"];
        player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];;

        [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        player.view.frame = CGRectMake(110,375,540,250);
        // player.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 375, 600, 415);
        [moviePlayer play];
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];

        //   [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
         //   [moviePlayer play];
         //   [moviePlayer pause];     // it preform action play pause ,stop
         //   [moviePlayer stop];
```